# Prefill Date Field In PHP Form To Be 3 Days In The Future

Tags: php

Below is the field that I want to be autofilled to 3 days in the future every time the user opens this form to create a new record. Right now it defaults to the current day. I've searched all over but I'm not entirely sure what I'm looking for. Thanks for your help.

```
<td><?php
echo $form->input(
    'Quote.date_due',
    array(
        'type'=>'date',
        'empty'=>false,
        'between'=>'<br />',
        'after'=>$html->link(
            $html->image(
                'calendar.png',
                array('width'=>'24','height'=>'24','alt'=>'Select Date')
            ),
            '#',
            array(
                'onclick'=>'displayCalendarSelectBox(document.forms[1].elements[10],document.forms[1].elements[8],document.forms[1].elements[9],false,false,this)'
            ),
            null,
            null,
            5
        )
    )
);
?></td>
```

Comment: Please attempt to format your code here so that it's readable.  Those attempting to help you shouldn't have to sift through one long line of code to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Also, please add some context and tags to your questions. Telling us what frameworks you are using will let us know what exactly we are looking at, and tags will make sure the right community members with the relevant knowledge look at your question. Other things that will help us include: PHP/Framework/OS Versions, installed plugins, what you have already tried, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP the [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) functions are useful for this.

**Example:**

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 days'));
```

**Output:**

```
2019-01-13
```

Just keep in mind that timezones can effect this, and that it is 3 days from the current time and not 3 days from today at midnight.

Comment: His field is `type=date` so no need for the time part

Comment: @Tucker81 I don't know what framework you are using to generate your form but it likely has an option for setting the "value" of an input. That's where you would put the code above.

Comment: I'm not sure where the code should go within the code that I provided. As for my framework, I'm using CakePHP.

Comment: @Tucker81 Then you need to take a look at the documentation for creating an input and see if it gives any clues on how to set the "value" attribute: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-input-elements

**Hint:** Click the links